# Make an index of historical time periods

Tags: indexing, datetime, fp

I'm writing my thesis & I want to make an index with centuries, years, month, day, event & historical periods. So I try to build some commands, but unsatisfactory, I'm looking for your help.

What are difficulties ?

- I have numerical datas & names (l'armistice, 15 janvier 1857, 1455, 19ème siècle)
- I have some composed periods (1801-1812, du 11ème au 13ème siècle)
- I need to indent my index (`event!day!month!year!centuries`)
- Sometime, I have only century, or year
- I want to classify all dates & centuries BCE (-200 ; -3 ; 23 ; 190 ; 1850 ; 2014)
- I don't know whether to make one or more commands

What I tried :

First step, a command for only centuries who's good, with a `*` for BCE centuries (For classify negatives centuries, I use fractions) :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}             
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}                    
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}         
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage{index}                                  
\usepackage{ifthen}                                 
\usepackage{ifmtarg}                                
\usepackage{fp}                                     

  \setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
  \addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\makeindex
\newindex{can}{cax}{cad}{Index des périodes} % makeindex period.cax -o period.cad
  \makeatletter\newcommand*{\sivide}{\@ifmtarg}\makeatother 
  \makeatletter\newcommand*{\sistar}{\@ifstar}\makeatother 

\newcommand*{\siglo}{\sistar\siglom\siglop}
\newcommand\siglop[1]%
 {\ifthenelse{#1 = 1}%                      
  {#1\up{er}~siècle de notre ère\index[can]{#1@#1\up{er}~siècle de notre ère}}%
  {#1\up{ème}~siècle\index[can]{#1@#1\up{ème}~siècle}}}%
\newcommand\siglom[1]%                          
 {\ifthenelse{#1 = 1}%
  {#1\up{er}~siècle avant notre ère\index[can]{0,6@1\up{er}~siècle avant notre ère}}%
  {#1\up{ème}~siècle avant notre ère\index[can]{\FPeval{\fraction}{1/#1}\fraction @#1\up{ème}~siècle avant notre ère}}}

\begin{document}
\siglo*{12} … \siglo*{1} … \siglo{14} … \siglo{1}
\printindex[can]
\end{document}
```

Another command (who remplace the first) for centuries & years, but my index fail :

```
    \newcommand*{\lan}{\sistar\lans\lano}
    \newcommand\lano[2]%
     {\sivide{#2}%
      {{\ifthenelse{#1 = 1}%                        
       {#1\up{er}~siècle de notre ère\index[can]{#1@#1\up{er}~siècle de notre ère}}%
       {#1\up{ème}~siècle\index[can]{#1@#1\up{ème}~siècle}}}}%
      {\sivide{#1}%
       {#2 de notre ère\index[can]{1\up{er}~siècle de notre ère!#2@#2}}%
       {#1#2\index[can]{\FPeval{\fraction}{#1+1}\fraction \up{ème}~siècle!#2@#1#2}}}}
    \newcommand\lans[2]%
     {\sivide{#2}%
      {{\ifthenelse{#1 = 1}%
       {#1\up{er}~siècle avant notre ère\index[can]{0,6@1\up{er}~siècle avant notre ère}}%
       {#1\up{ème}~siècle avant notre ère\index[can]{\FPeval{\fraction}{1/#1}\fraction @#1\up{ème}~siècle avant notre ère}}}}
      {\sivide{#1}%
       {-#2\index[can]{1\up{er}~siècle avant notre ère!\FPeval{\fraction}{1/#2}\fraction @-#2}}%
       {-#1#2\index[can]{\FPeval{\fraction}{#1+1}\fraction \up{ème}~siècle avant notre ère !\FPeval{\fraction}{1/#2}\fraction @-#1#2}}}}
```

and in the text

```
\lan*{12}{} … \lan*{1}{} … \lan{14}{} … \lan{1}{} … 

\lan*{11}{16} … \lan*{}{18} … \lan{}{20} … \lan{19}{90} …
```

So after, I'm stuck !
Thank you for your help

Comment: @Torbjørn_T. Tanks for edition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after several hours of hard amateur work, I publish the command I'd baptized `\qd` like the french word "quand" (which means "when"). That's the complete form : `\qd*[]{}{}{}{}{}{}`. I explain you the use :

- I put `*` for negative dates, nothing for positives dates
- the first argument `[#1]` is a text argument with different usages. Look at [the complete code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ffsbc9ibpfaqq2/Dateindex.tex) for greater understanding. If I want to write an event, for exemple `[french Revolution]`, it's the place to.  If I want only write a date, I propose 7 options :

  - `[]` nothing for single form of the date
  - `[l]` for using a long form
  - `[c]` for the short form (forme courte in french)
  - `[t]` for the very short form (forme très courte)
  - `[j]` for the single form with de name of the day of week (jour) from 1901
  - `[jc]` for the short form with de name of the day of week (jour court)
  - `[jt]` for the very short form with de name of the day of week (jour très court)
- The 6 other arguments represent the date elements :

  - `{#2}` millenium (0 to ∞)
  - `{#3}` century (0 to 9)
  - `{#4}` decade (0 to 9)
  - `{#5}` year (0 to 9)
  - `{#6}` month (1 to 12)
  - `{#7}` day (1 to 31)

Look, here some exemples :

```
Le \qd*[Néolithique]{10}{}{}{}{}{} commence au \qd*[]{10}{}{}{}{}{}, \\
Des \qd*[hiéroglyphes]{3}{2}{}{}{}{} à l'\qd*[alphabet phénicien]{1}{1}{}{}{}{} \\
Les \qd*[c]{1}{0}{}{}{}{}, \qd*[c]{1}{1}{}{}{}{}, \\ 
En \qd*[l]{0}{9}{8}{3}{}{} & dans les \qd*[]{2}{0}{0}{}{}{}, \\
En \qd*[]{0}{3}{3}{2}{}{}-\qd*[c]{0}{3}{3}{1}{}{}, Alexandre devient pharaon, \\
Le \qd*[l]{0}{0}{4}{4}{3}{15}, on entendit un \qd*[\emph{tu quoque}]{0}{0}{4}{4}{3}{15}, \\
Le \qd*[c]{0}{0}{0}{1}{12}{25}, Marie cria, \\
\qd[l]{0}{0}{0}{9}{1}{1}, \\
Les \qd[c]{1}{0}{}{}{}{} & \qd[c]{1}{1}{}{}{}{}, \\ 
L'\qd[hégire]{0}{6}{2}{2}{7}{16}, \\
Le \qd[]{1}{7}{8}{9}{7}{14} changea la destinée de la France, \\
Du \qd[jc]{1}{9}{9}{9}{12}{31} au \qd[j]{2}{0}{0}{0}{1}{1}, \\
Du \qd[jt]{1}{9}{8}{4}{1}{1} au \qd[j]{1}{9}{8}{4}{1}{2}, jour de \qd[naissance]{1}{9}{8}{4}{1}{2}.
```

This is the text :

[image: The text]

& the index :

[image: The index]

I encountered some difficulties which I summarize here with solutions:

- For ranking the negatives dates in the index who don't know negative numbers, I use in the command some fractions like `1/((#2)+1)`, thereby rank for millenium in index is good : -3(=1/4), -2(=1/3), -1(=1/2), 1, 2, 3…,
- for differences between 18th century `\qd[]{1}{8}{}{}{}{}` linked in the index with 1789 `\qd[]{1}{7}{8}{9}{}{}`, I use some additions (look at [the complete code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ffsbc9ibpfaqq2/Dateindex.tex))
- I make differences between first (millenium, century, decade or year) and others, for exemple `\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{0}}{…}{…}`, because year 2000 is in the 2th millenium, 20th century, but in the 2000 decade… (look at [the complete code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ffsbc9ibpfaqq2/Dateindex.tex) ;)
- I'm using now arara & some packages like `datetime`, `fp` awkwardly, `glossaries` & `imakeidx`, big evolution for me.

So, I put her the command &  [the complete code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ffsbc9ibpfaqq2/Dateindex.tex), because it seems to long here.
I see some errors in the compilation, but, it look perfectly in the document.
If someone want to simplify this heavy command, I listen to your proposals.
Thanks for your help. Bye

Comment: tenacious work! ;-)

Comment: to improve, isn't it ?

Comment: But, I'm unable to use the package `seealso`! Any idea ?

Comment: I suggest you try [`seealso`](http://ctan.org/pkg/seealso) package and possibly make a new questio.

Comment: @jfbu I tried here, but for now without success : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179628/seealso-package-dont-run-with-my-index-command