# seealso package don't run with my index command

Tags: glossaries, indexing, xindy

I built (with your help [in this conversation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163434/make-an-index-of-historical-time-periods)) a command to have an index with historical dates & events, index in time order like a timeline. In this artisanal command, I have firstly only dates in chronological order with the page numbers, and secondly in alphabetic order: events items. Now, I would like to use the `seealso` package to see appear page numbers near events too. Apparently, it doesn't work. My command is detailed without `seealso` [in this complete code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ffsbc9ibpfaqq2/Dateindex.tex). I use it in my text like that, for exemple (*voir* = *see* in french) :

- french first abolition of slavery : `\qd[abolition de l'esclavage]{1}{7}{9}{4}{2}{4}`
- it run in the main text : abolition de l'esclavage
- in the index, first : 4 février 1794, 1
- in the index in the A lettre : abolition de l'esclavage, *voir* le 4 février 1794

I'm using `xelatex`, `xindy` and this config with `seealso` :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = arara
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}                    
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}         
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{seealso}

\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage[xindy={language=french, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[xindy, splitindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\makeatletter\newcommand*{\sivide}{\@ifmtarg}\makeatother
\makeatletter\newcommand*{\sistar}{\@ifstar}\makeatother 
\def\makeampletter{\catcode`\&11\relax}             
\def\makeampcolsep{\catcode`\&4\relax} 

% datetime
\renewcommand{\fmtord}[1]{\up{#1}}% 
\makeatletter\patchcmd{\@ordinalMfrench}{eme}{ème}{}{}\makeatother
%\fmtcountsetoptions{abbrv}% 

\makeglossaries
\def\xindylangopt{-M lang/french/utf8-lang -M style1.xdy}
\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
\makeindex[name=can, title=Index des dates, options=\xindylangopt, columnseprule=true] 
\sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=1} %
```

& some other commands I'll detail [in this complete code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ffsbc9ibpfaqq2/Dateindex.tex). 
So, I show you the clean index result without using `seealso` here : [clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Qx1.png)

And, using the package `seealso` & fonction! (zoom on my events, the problem) :

[image: seealso]

And, I show you too a detail of one of .log blocking :

```
(./Dateindex-can.ind
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
<recently read> ##

l.71 ...rdinalnum {11}~siècle avant notre ère}{}

? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.71 ...rdinalnum {11}~siècle avant notre ère}{}

? 
! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.71 ...rdinalnum {11}~siècle avant notre ère}{}

? 
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.71 ...rdinalnum {11}~siècle avant notre ère}{}

? 
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> }
```

Sorry, it like a debugging, but I stuck. I suspect that it may be an incompatibility between my command `\qd` & the running way of `seealso` package, an argument problem. Take a look !
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to reduce your code to a MWE. I had a look at the dropbox file and obviously it would take a lot of time to read and process it.