# fmtcount problems with french & newcommand

Tags: babel, datetime, french, fmtcount

I built & used [a complex command `\qd`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163434/make-an-index-of-historical-time-periods) this spring who requires `datetime` package and therefore `fmtcount`. I start again to use my command these days, but occurred some changes. I suspect updates of `fmtcount` package. Problems:

1. Though I put `frenchb` option in `babel` package, results of `numberstringnum`& `ordinalnum` commands are in english…
2. Now, I can't use this form for my command: `\numberstringnum{{#1}0}`, & it's very troublesome.

I put here a minimal exemple :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = arara
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}                    
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}         
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\qd}[1]{années~\numberstringnum{{#1}0}}

\begin{document}
\numberstringnum{300}, \ordinalnum{3}[m], \formatdate{1}{1}{2000}…
%\qd{8}.
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
```

And the result :s

[image]

In the example above, I commented out the second problem I meet (`%\qd{8}.`). If I active the `\qd` command, error messages in the console are:

```
! Missing number
…
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum
…
! Package fmtcount error: Out of range
```

I have the 3.00 version of [`fmtcount` package manual](http://www.dickimaw-books.com). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Load `\usepackage[french]{fmtcount}` before `datetime`.

Comment: @egreg Cool ! it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either put the `french` (or `frenchb`) option as a global option to `\documentclass` or load

```
\usepackage[french]{fmtcount}
```

before `datetime`. The problem, apparently, is that the `fmtcount` package doesn't look at the default `babel` language when it's loaded.

So, either

```
\documentclass[frenchb]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}

%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\qd}[1]{années~\numberstringnum{{#1}0}}

\begin{document}
\numberstringnum{300}, \ordinalnum{3}[m], \formatdate{1}{1}{2000}…
\qd{8}.
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{fmtcount}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}

%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\qd}[1]{années~\numberstringnum{{#1}0}}

\begin{document}
\numberstringnum{300}, \ordinalnum{3}[m], \formatdate{1}{1}{2000}…
\qd{8}.
\end{document}
```

(I commented the font selection as I don't have that font.)