# ordinalnum & roman small-capitals numbers

Tags: small-caps, french, roman-numerals, fmtcount

I'm using `ordinalnum` command many times in [a big command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163434/make-an-index-of-historical-time-periods), this is very helpful. I would have like my ordinal number in small caps & `romannumeral` according french norm of typography for centuries notation. Of course, impossible to put the first command in the second & vice versa. My minimal configuration :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = arara
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}                    
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}         
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{fmtcount}

% \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\textsc{\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}}

\begin{document}
\ordinalnum{1} siècle,  \ordinalnum{21} siècle.\\
\RNum{1}\up{er} siècle, \RNum{21}\up{eme} siècle.
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
```

[image]

Some idea to use `ordinalnum` command with entirety functionality (good suffix up etc.) & numbers in roman numbering & small-caps ? Thanks.

Comment: Comment aside, the abbevaition for the ordinal superscript in French is not `eme` but simply`e`. There seems to be an error in the localisation module of `fmtcount`.

Comment: I'll write to the French author, as I had once a dicussion with about some functionalities of the `lettre` class. What is odd isn't the error *per se* (it is rather common), but the fact that the French module of babel doen't make this error.

Comment: Btw, `frenchb` already has `ier`, `\ieme`, &c., commands.

Comment: @Zouib: thanks, couldn't remember when it was exactly. Maybe you could even suggest your publication staff to use a superscript `ième` (the only correct use I know for the form is `n-ième`, although in non-scientific texts, one usually writes `enième`;o).

Comment: @Bernard good. I use now more strictly the `lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale` norms : 1er, 1re, 2e, & for centuries I try to use Ier, IIe (in small caps), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can offer a *-variant for `\ordinalnum` that prints the number in small caps Roman numerals.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}                    
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}         
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{fmtcount}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd{\@ordinalnum}
  {\cE.\c{@fc@ordstr}}
  {\cE\}\c{format@fc@ordstr}}
  {}{}
\def\format@fc@ordstr{%
  \begingroup
  \if@tempswa
    \scshape\romannumeral
  \fi
  \@fc@ordstr
  \endgroup
}
\xpatchcmd{\fmtord}{#1}{\upshape#1}{}{}
\let\fmtcount@ordinalnum\ordinalnum
\renewcommand{\ordinalnum}{%
  \@ifstar{\@tempswatrue\fmtcount@ordinalnum}%
          {\@tempswafalse\fmtcount@ordinalnum}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ordinalnum*{1} siècle,  \ordinalnum*{21} siècle, \ordinalnum{3}[f] place.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you can't use `regexpatch`, because of other packages loading `xpatch`, you can replace the first four lines after `\makeatletter` by

```
\def\@ordinalnum#1[#2]{%
  {%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{f}}%
    {%
      \protect\@ordinalF{#1}{\@fc@ordstr}%
    }%
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{n}}%
      {%
        \protect\@ordinalN{#1}{\@fc@ordstr}%
      }%
      {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{m}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \PackageError{fmtcount}%
           {Invalid gender option `#2'}%
           {Available options are m, f or n}%
        }%
        \protect\@ordinalM{#1}{\@fc@ordstr}%
      }%
    }%
    \format@fc@ordstr
  }%
}
```

which does the same thing. Remember to remove `\usepackage{regexpatch}`.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old discussion, but I would like to submit my solution based on Lua. Tested with *lualatex*. Criticism is welcome.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function PrintFrenchOrdinalRoman(ANumber)
  local LStr = '\\textsc{\\romannumeral ' .. tostring(ANumber) .. '}' ..
    (ANumber == 1 and '\\ier' or '\\ieme')
  tex.sprint(LStr)
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\ordinalroman[1]{\directlua{PrintFrenchOrdinalRoman(#1)}}

\begin{document}

C'était au \textsc{i}\ier~siècle.

C'était au \textsc{ii}\ieme~siècle.

C'était au \textsc{\romannumeral 1}\ier~siècle.

C'était au \textsc{\romannumeral 2}\ieme~siècle.

C'était au \luaexec{PrintFrenchOrdinalRoman(1)}~siècle.

C'était au \luaexec{PrintFrenchOrdinalRoman(2)}~siècle.

C'était au \ordinalroman{1}~siècle.

C'était au \ordinalroman{2}~siècle.

Nous sommes au \luaexec{PrintFrenchOrdinalRoman(os.date('*t').year // 100 + 1)}~siècle.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Other solution**

Other solution using only LaTeX. Inspired from [this discussion](https://geekographie.maieul.net/7).

```
% Tested with lualatex

\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
\usepackage{babel}

\newcommand*{\ordinalroman}[1]{%
\ifnum#1=1%
\textsc{\romannumeral #1}\ier%
\else%
\textsc{\romannumeral #1}\ieme%
\fi}

\begin{document}

C'était au \textsc{i}\ier~siècle.

C'était au \textsc{ii}\ieme~siècle.

C'était au \textsc{\romannumeral 1}\ier~siècle.

C'était au \textsc{\romannumeral 2}\ieme~siècle.

C'était au \ordinalroman{1}~siècle.

C'était au \ordinalroman{2}~siècle.

Nous sommes au \ordinalroman{\directlua{tex.sprint(os.date('*t').year // 100 + 1)}}~siècle.

\end{document}
```

Criticism still welcome. I have a doubt if it is better to use `\newcommand` or `\newcommand*`.