# Display an index of dates

Tags: indexing, date

I write a document which tells a story long of a few months, and I would like to display an index of the main dates at the end. For example, I would like to type something like (french format): `On January the first \indexdate{01/01/2018}...`, so the final index would look like this.

```
- 2018
January, 1st : 2
January, 3rd : 4, 6
January, 21th : 12-13, 15
```

Is there a package which would allow me to do something like this? Or, is it possible to do a such index without having to manually compute a timestamp or something for the ordering of each date? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Often it helps to do a google search like `site:tex.stackexchange.com index date` in this case, which has lead me to 
[this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176995/121799). I am not saying that this is necessarily the answer to your question, but would suggest that you go through the results of such searches in order to get a feeling of what has already been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof of concept that should be easily adaptable to your purpose and language.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[english]{datetime2}
\usepackage[level]{fmtcount}

\makeindex

\newcommand{\indexdate}[1]{% date in format MM-DD
  \index{#1@\computedate{#1}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\computedate}[1]{\compute@date#1\@nil}
\def\compute@date#1-#2\@nil{%
  \DTMenglishmonthname{#1}\space\ordinalnum{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This happened on January 1st\indexdate{01-01}.

This happened on July 4th\indexdate{07-04}.

This happened on December 25th\indexdate{12-25}.

\clearpage

This happened on October 31st\indexdate{10-31}.

This happened on January 1st\indexdate{01-01}.

This happend on January 13th\indexdate{01-13}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

There's actually no need that `\indexdate` follows a date, here it's done just for ease of verification of the output.

It's important to express the date in numeric format (with two digits) for correct sorting.

[image]

If the header is modified into

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[french]{datetime2}
\usepackage[level]{fmtcount}

\makeindex

\newcommand{\indexdate}[1]{% date in format MM-DD
  \index{#1@\computedate{#1}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\computedate}[1]{\compute@date#1\@nil}
\def\compute@date#1-#2\@nil{%
  \DTMfrenchordinal{#2} \DTMfrenchmonthname{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

the same document body as before would produce

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I slightly modified your code to have different entries for different years and months, so I have the following: `\makeindex[name=dateindex, title=Index des dates] \newcommand{\indexdate}[3]{\index[dateindex]{#3!\DTMfrenchmonthname{#2}!#3#2#1@\DTMdate{#3-#2-#1}}}`.